# How to achieve 3-5-4 grid layout by using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

[image]

---

I have been trying to create a grid layout as above with Bootstrap but couldn't figure out a way to do it, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly quite simple using nested rows. The problem comes if you want exactly 3/5 columns for the left two. You can get close by simply doing this which makes it almost right, is this enough?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">IMAGE1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">TEXT1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">IMAGE2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">TEXT3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">SIDEBAR</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need *exactly* 3/5/4 layout then then only sensible way to do it while still using Bootstrap would be to [customise](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) the grid system to get the granularity. In this case you need to make it a 24 column layout which would make your grid look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-16">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">IMAGE1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-15">TEXT1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">IMAGE2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-15">TEXT3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">SIDEBAR</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may also want to include a .clearfix div after each TEXT element. That would make sure everything is okay.

Comment: Yes I want exactly 3/5 columns

Comment: @Edward Then that isn't possible with the default Bootstrap implementation. You would need to customise the files, see my edit.

Comment: @DavidG Very smart! I'm already using a customized version but didn't notice columns number can be changed, will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @David I meant that since the two elements are floated, they should be cleared afterwards.

Comment: @RomiHalasz You do know that Bootstrap handles all of that stuff for you right?